# What is the rule in the sentence "she always had this twisted side to her"?

Tags: idioms

I can understand the meaning of the sentence "she always had this twisted side to her", but I can't really figure out why it is expressed like this. I mean, if I couldn't get the meaning, how should have I searched for it in the dictionary? Is it a particular use of the verb "to have"? Or of "to"?

For me it would be more natural to just say "she always had this twisted side".
I hope it is clear what I'm trying to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an extended way of saying "she always had this twisted side". The seemingly-redundant "to her" you can read as "belonging to her" or "attached to her" or "about her". It's a common trope in everyday English.

Comment: This is quite clear. I'm still wondering whether I can find such a use listed in the dictionary definition. Before asking here I carefully looked up definitions on three online dictionaries with no luck

Comment: No, you're not likely to find phrases like this in ordinary dictionaries, which deal mainly with individual words. But the bigger dictionaries such as the full-size Oxford English Dictionary, might have what you're looking for.